# How do I find shortcuts to run queries on the QuestDB console?

Tags: questdb

I'm using the QuestDB console (https://questdb.io/docs/reference/web-console) and I would like to know if there are keyboard shortcuts for operations such as running queries?

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl+Enter also runs the query or Command+Enter on Mac crippled of F keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `F2` to locate the cursor and `F9` to run the query at the cursor location or the highlighted selection.